# jQuery UI Tabs - Bottom of the tab bar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am wanting to include a logo image in my tab bar, but it is causing the tabs to not be at the bottom of the tab bar. Here is the code I am using:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="./img/logo.png">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="./eventlog.html">Event Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am attaching a screenshot of what it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: why not make the image smaller so that the height fits the tabs

Comment: Just working with the logo I was given.

Comment: Then send the above screen shot to the designer and ask whether (s)he would think a small image would do better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `<li>` the height of the logo, and set a `margin-top` with the difference between the height of the image and the height of the `<li>`.

Comment: I can force it this way (by editing the jquery-ui css file) but I was hoping to find an option I was missing somewhere that could control that from the javascript.

Comment: Can't you import your own CSS code after the jQuery UI, that overrides the class of the `<li>`?

Comment: Ended up just editing the jquery-ui file and changing the top margin for the tabs. So when I download a new theme it is just one little change to make.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new row (I mean `<br />`):

```
<div id="tabs">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="./img/logo.png">
  </div>
  <br />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="./eventlog.html">Event Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or maybe the tab bar and the logo aren't supposed to be in the same `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="logo">
  <img src="./img/logo.png">
</div>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="./eventlog.html">Event Log</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That shortens the entire background behind the tabs as well. I am wanting to leave that the same height, just move the tabs themselves to the bottom.

Comment: maybe the logo and the tab bar shouldn't be in the same <div>

Comment: I don't think so. Is the page loading a specific CSS-file? in that case: you should look over the css to see the different layouts for "logo" and "tabs"

Comment: The logo div doesn't have any CSS behind it at the moment, and the tabs div is from the jquery-ui css file. I was hoping to not have to mess with the jquery-ui css file since any upgrades in the future would break it. I may just have to do that though, see the answer by @Hidde

Comment: Agree, I wish it was way more simpler but unfortunately you have to override the jquery-css or declare new css-settings for the "logo". My advice to make it easier is the last option